# DB2/400 : ALTER TABLE foreign key

Tags: db2, alter-table

I am having a SQL problem on a DB2/400 database.

I would like to know  if there is a particular method for adding a constraint on a foreign key of a table.

Right now, I'm using the statement below to declare a foreign key
in the table "TABELE_A" of the schema "MY_SCHEMA":

```
alter table MY_SCHEMA.TABELE_A  
foreign key (IDAUTO_B)  references MY_SCHEMA.TABELE_B   (IDAUTO_B).
```

The "ALTER TABLE" statement runs without problems.

But as soon as I make an "update" in the table "MY_SCHEMA.TABELE_B ", I have a crash.

> The SQL code error is SQL7008 and the  reason code is 3 : "MY_SCHEMA.TABELE_B" not journaled, no rights on the journal or the state of the log is * STANDBY.

My question is : is it necessary logging tables to set up a referenciel integrity on SQL DB2/400 data-base ?